# Discord Javascript webhook filtering for my website as an updater

Tags: javascript, discord

I thought I had this situated but I guess not. I have a script that when a webpage is updated it tells discord that it's been updated. To get around having to use a button to trigger it, I put it into a body onload. However, while it works as intended for me, others that visit the page end up spamming my discord. Is there a way to filter this so the script is triggered once by me and no one else? I did look around and it doesn't seem there's anything that fits this exact situation, or similar.

Thanks in advance, Matt

My Code:

```
<script>
  const current = document.lastModified;
  const previous = localStorage.getItem('lastModified'); // Get the last known modified timestamp
  localStorage.setItem('lastModified', current); // Update the current modified timestamp
  if (current !== previous) { 
   
     function FNR() {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("POST", "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/736073177125355570/yn5upyFa_7IkqwRXlO9XPzooIyMWkqM7wIXcIjqSR6SlhYD8eBCWOm7vEVl4vmNjQBxL");
      request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
      var params = {
        username: "PandaUpdater",
        avatar_url: "",
        content: "@here Hey everyone! Jenn updated her site, take a look! http://fnreborn.tk/pjenn"
      }
      request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
    }    
}
  </script>
```

Comment: giving this a bump as I haven't found an answer to my problem.